# How To Trick WeChat Into to Thinking My iPhone Is An iPad?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, sandbox

so I use a chatting app called WeChat and I have two phones. It only allows me to sign in on one phone at a time. But I can sign in on an iPad and a phone at the same time. It's an universal app, which means there is no iPad specific ipa. I like to know how I can put WeChat into a sandbox and makes it think my iPhone is an iPad. Thanks.

Comment: As an iOS app developer, I know that you basically just ask "which device style is this?" and it will return `.Pad` or `.Phone`. It determines this based on the preinstalled system; of course, iOS is different on iPhones and iPads and it's preloaded with a little "what am I" that the user (you) just can't change. You're out of luck here.

Comment: @JohnRamos What you mean is the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key, which I suspect can be spoofed if we know how.

Comment: There are a few ways to determine the device one's app is being run on: first, `UIDevice.CurrentDevice` returns something like `iPhone 6,2` or `iPad 5,1`, and second, `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` which returns `.Pad` or `.Phone`. Both are ingrained into the version of iOS your device gets, and really can't be changed without a jailbreak. A `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key is different: that does one thing, which is preventing an app from being installed on a device without a certain feature. So WeChat could prevent their app from being installed on iPad with that; not what's going on here!

Comment: Quote from Apple's Documentation about `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`: "Do not add a UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key unless you actively need to restrict installation of your application based on the availability or lack of availability of a device feature." So to conclude, you just can't trick WeChat into thinking your iPhone is an iPad.

Comment: Is there a method to intercept `UIDevice.CurrentDevice` or `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` on a jailbroken iPhone?

Comment: I found this, though I have no idea if it'll work: https://m.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/2mhp2e/ipad_apps_on_iphone/

Comment: @JohnRamos That's really for iPad only apps to run on iPhones. For universal apps, the perm is already 0775.

Comment: OK, I really don't know how you would fake those. I doubt you can, but to get more attention you could ask that as a new question or amend that to this question and pose a bounty. Also, have you tried requesting the desktop site of the web version of WeChat on your second phone?

Comment: @aeroxy Yes, you can intercept basically anything on a jailbroken device.

Comment: @JohnRamos it works but the feature on a desktop site is limited. No video calls or audio calls available, and many other features like wechat pay. Also desktop site's UI on a mobile phone is practically unusable.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson how do I intercept `UIDevice.CurrentDevice` or `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`?

Comment: @aeroxy yeah, that's understandable. Huh.

Comment: @aeroxy You have to write an application with Mobile Substrate.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson how do I intercept `UIDevice.CurrentDevice` or `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` with Mobile Substrate? Have you personally done it before?

Comment: @aeroxy Not those particular calls, but I have a couple Mobile Substrate applications on GitHub https://github.com/developersBliss You're best taking this over to StackOverflow, though.

Comment: @aeroxy So thinking back, I think it's possible that WeChat could be employing a third method here: querying the system for the size of the screen (which you can call for in mm) and deducing from that whether it's an iPad or iPhone. This can get murky/unreliable if the iPad is in split view, or if it's an iPhone 6s Plus vs an iPad Mini, but I think that theoretically would work for them too.

Comment: If we're talking about specific calls, they're `UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.width` and `UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.height` to find the size of the application window, as well as `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width` and `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height` to find the whole screen's size.

Comment: I would take a look at overloading sysctl calls - it's very low level and would be queried by most high(er) level methods such as UIDevice etc. It's been done in [this substrate tweak](https://github.com/hamzasood/SiriAuthFix/blob/master/SiriAuthFix/SiriAuthFix.mm).

Comment: If you have two iPhones, have you considered just signing up for two accounts and have one for each? I'm assuming one's a work phone. I know it would be annoying to add you contacts to the other profile.

Answer (score 1):

The WeChat app can ask iOS whether it is running on an iPad or iPhone. It is not something you can set in Settings, or "fake" through the Messages settings as indicated elsewhere.

The only way to overcome this is with a jailbroken iPhone, where you can intercept the relevant method calls. In practice it is not possible to do so for an "ordinary user" without strong technical skills.

Try contacting WeChat support to see if they have a work-around, or they might consider lifting the restriction in coming versions.

Comment: What's the tool u used to intercept the communication between an app and iOS?

Comment: Cydia Substrate (http://www.cydiasubstrate.com)

Comment: It looks like in the WeChat.app folder, there is a `info.strings` file where I can modify `UIDeviceFamily` from 1 to 2 (from iPhone to iPad), unfortunately it does not impact how the device run WeChat (or any other apps) on an iPhone. It looks like it does allow iPad to run some iPhone apps in 1024*768 or 960 retina resolutions.

Comment: My guess is that they limit it to one device 'by design'. If they only allow one device ( of the same kind ) they can more easily identify compromised accounts. If you're using your account on an iPhone and someone else uses an iPhone and hacks your password, only one account will be allowed... which should throw up warning flags.

Answer (score -1):

Since I am not allowed to "comment" I will respond here. Look at your iPhone and iPad Settings for Messages/Send a Receive. You should see either phone numbers or/and email addresses or both. Perhaps you will see a categorical difference between the iPhone setting and that for the iPad. It may show you why WeChat sees the as two different types of "things". This is obviously just a guess. Good luck.

Comment: WeChat does not have access to the Messages.app settings, so it cannot learn your phone number and/or AppleID email adresses from there.